# Add a pop up modal to WooCommerce product "view more" button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a wordpress website which has a product page, listing products in a grid. All products are as in the picture below. 
[products grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEbqo.jpg)

I want to know: when click on the view more button, a pop up shows, which has 2 columns, in the left, product full description and images, at the right a form, with placeholders and options and a submit order button. the goal is when click sumbit after client entered all data, the product, with all data that has been entered send as an email to the admin.

I naturally dont want all the code needed, just the workflow. like first do this, then do that and etc...

Appreciate all helps

Comment: Your description of needs is not clear enough to make an accurate step plan. But I think you should do trigger an Ajax call with an `.on( 'click', '*view more button*')`. Your Ajax call should trigger an PHP function which returns all of the needed data for yourproduct details popup. This data will be provided with some WooCommerce functions that can be used with the product_ID that you could store either in the `show more button` or in a hidden field. You could append this data to any div by using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks alot, which part of my question is unclear? So I can describe better and get a better solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here, this should be more than enough to get you started.

First you need to add the css, js elements to your page, you can add them separately into CSS, and JS files using WordPress enqueue hook, this is just basic example:

I copied the Modal sample on: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp to use in this example.

```
function pop_up() {
?>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="content-left">
         <!-- Leave empty to be able to populate later with ajax -->
    </div>

    <div class="content-right">
         <!-- Put your form here -->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<style>
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
// Let's do the magic
    // make sure to change #myBtn to read more button selector
    $(document).on("click","#myBtn",function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    // get url
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var container = $('#myModal').find('.content-left');
        var data = {
            action: 'show_product',
            url: url,

        };
        $.post('<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data, function(response) {
           // display the response
           console.log(response);
           $(container).empty();       
           $(container).html(response);
            modal.style.display = "block";
        });
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'pop_up' );
```

Now we will create a response with php based on the url send by the post request, you can use this to get product image, content, description, price or anything, and put it together to return it in HTML form inside ajax response to display it inside the modal

```
add_action('wp_ajax_show_product', 'show_product_callback_wp');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_show_product', 'show_product_callback_wp' );
function show_product_callback_wp() {
     $url = $_POST['url'];
     $product_id = url_to_postid( $url );

    // product content
    $content_post = get_post($product_id);
    $content = $content_post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

     $output = "";
     $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $product_id, 'medium');;
     $output .= $content;

     echo $output;
     exit(); 
}
```

This is tested and working.

Comment: Thanks Ali_k for help. but I'm kind of new to wordpress development, where should i put these codes you mentioned? the problem is I don't know the wordpress flow very good, and no idea about ajax and jquery either, I need to know how to assemble these codes! thanks again

Comment: This goes in you functions.php, change button id here to the your button selector and save  `$(document).on("click","#myBtn",function(e) ` then you  need to take care of the layout

Comment: I'm using VC post grid. in VC grid builder there's a JS function option for the button(as in the picture) what should I put here? Picture: [link](http://kavistudio.ir/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/VC-button.jpg)

Comment: save it like that and change to this: `$(document).on("click",".myBtn",function(e)`